# DISNAKE Как написать в канал от имени бота в коге?

Tags: python, discord

Проблема заключается в том, что это Ког, в обычном файле можно сделать так: `channel = bot.get_channel(ID)` в коге он начинает жаловаться.
Ошибка если напишу "`bot.get_channel(ID)`":
`NameError: name 'bot' is not defined`
Ошибка если напишу "`commands.get_channel(ID)`": `AttributeError: module 'disnake.ext.commands' has no attribute 'get_channel'`
Оно то и понятно в чём заключается ошибка, но как её решить не знаю.
код в коге:

`import disnake from disnake.ext import commands`

`class Economic(commands.Cog): def __init__(self, bot=commands.Bot): self.bot = bot`

```
@commands.command(name="award", aliases= ["AWARD", "Award"])
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True, administrator=True)
async def add_money(self, ctx, member: disnake.Member = None,amount: int = None):

    channel = commands.get_channel(id)
```

`def setup(bot:commands.Bot): bot.add_cog(Economic(bot)) print(f"Cog Economic is ready")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо ***`bot.get_channel(ID)`*** используйте ***`self.bot.get_channel(ID)`***

Comment: Спасибо, помогло